# local database using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

This is my situation: I want to make a small application in C# using SQL server, but I don't want it to be a server based application...

I simply want a database that I can copy and paste into my application folder and reference it there, then use the application on any other PC that wont have SQL Server installed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with SQL Server database. You can use <strike>[Microsoft Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/) database  or</strike> [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) for this purpose or you can use [SQL Server CE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx).

See: [How to: Deploy a SQL Server Compact 4.0 Database with an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Very close to -1 for recommending JET/ACE as an "answer" to anything. And since he's trying to avoid installing SQL Server, I doubt he wants Access installed in one way or anything. Which leaves JET, which is x86 only. And crap.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, actually YES. SQLite or CE should  be the option

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I decided to just bite the bullet and go for mySQL. Which is easy to install and free, and does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use embedded solution such as `SQL SERVER CE`. Look at [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [Microsoft LocalDb](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx) which are both filebased and you can copy/paste and you're done.

For compatibility with SQL Server, Microsoft LocalDb is your winner, in the sense that if you want you can switch connection strings to a fully fledged SQL Server that has the same schema and it will work.

If you don't need that then SQLite is a lightweight and sufficient choice, there is a free Ado.net provider for it, you can use it with EntityFramework, absolutely no problem, just don't expect it to work Model-first or Code-first. You will have to go Database-first.

Comment: Beat me to it! I was going to suggest this!

Comment: -1 "any other PC that wont have SQL Server installed" LocalDB has to be installed.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - sorry, Windows 8 comes with it preinstalled :D, of course not all computers will have Win 8 but hey, look to the future right?

Comment: "sorry, Windows 8 comes with it preinstalled :D" No it does not.